# How can I turn off iCloud?

Tags: macos, icloud

As far as I can tell, I have all iCloud settings turned off, but I am still incessantly asked to log into iCloud. Is it possible to not use iCloud without being reminded every 5 minutes to log into iCloud? I'm on a MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.5. Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

In your system settings go to iCloud and make sure you have all of the switches set to off.  If you have any other devices (iPad, iPhone) do the same.  Open Mail, iTunes, Messages, etc.. all the default apps, and make sure your settings are disabled in each.

[In this article](http://www.rawinfopages.com/mac/content/keep-being-asked-your-icloud-password), it's mentioned, that this may be a bug with OSX and by clearing all your cache and then turning the switches all on, saving, and off again may resolve the issue.

Running this command in terminal will disable applications from like Textedit from trying to save to iCloud by default:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool FALSE
```

and this command should disable the iCloud prompt when you login

```
sudo defaults write "/System/Library/User Template/Non_localized/Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant" DidSeeCloudSetup -bool TRUE
```

(Note the quotes are required since one of the pathname components, "User Template", has an embedded space.)

Comment: Note that running `sudo` commands without knowing exactly what they do is potentially _very dangerous_ to your system's well-being. This particular one modifies the User Template default preferences to bypass the iCloud setup tool.

Comment: Thank you. I currently have all icloud settings turned off on both macbook pro and iphone6. These are the only two apple devices in the mix.

When running the sudo command, I am told the -bool is an unexpected argument and defaults have been left unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I have an older Mac Mini at OS X10.10.5, on which the **iCloud preferences** dialog got to be a bug.

One can ignore the dialog by clicking on its **Later** button

The dialog appears more often the longer it is ignored. It first appeared a few months back as a weekly thing. Nowadays it pops up a few times a day.

From the other answer I looked in **System Preferences > iCloud** but everything was off already.

So I went to **System Preferences > Internet Accounts** and clicked in **iCloud**, then clicked on the small `-` button at the bottom of the dialog, to delete it.

I held its hand through all the great features I was losing, confirming all of them as deleted.

Comment: The dialog has now stayed away for a few albums. 

Current track: "The Weeping Song" from "The Good Son" by Nick Cave & The Bad Seeds.

Comment: Thanks for the upgrade @agarza